# Join two tables with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Take the following example entities:

```
Entity Child {
    long id;
    String name;
    long parentKey;
}

Entity Parent {
    long id;
    String desc;
}
```

Is there a way with Hibernate Criteria queries:

```
select * from Child c, Parent p 
         where c.parentKey = p.id and c.name = "whatever" and p.desc = "whatever"
```

Our main concern is **how to do join with Criteria across two entities that are only related
by the long key**.

Assume that we **can't** put a reference to Parent directly in our Child.

Comment: Would "not have a reference to Parent directly in our Child" imply that its a uni-directional relation from Parent to Child

Comment: must they be longs ? could you create a Key object for the child ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what Hibernate version are you referring to, but in JPA 2.0 something like this is possible:

```
String query = "SELECT c FROM Child c, Parent p WHERE c.parentId = p.id";

List<Child> children = em.createQuery(query, Child.class).getResultList();
```

In this way you're explicitly doing JOIN based on your custom condition instead of letting JPA manage it, albeit it's perfectly legal to do so.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thank you for your reply.  If we want the result set to contain data from both Child and Parent (not just the Child), I know that HQL can handle, but is there any way to use the Criteria API?  Or does Criteria only allow for returning a specific class of entity? (e.g. either Parent or Child but not both)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to understand it. The query I've posted returns only `Child` entities - not `Parent` **and** `Child`. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I voted down this answer because the question was about the **Criteria API**